# How to import csv file via woocommerce import csv suite

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am totally new to WooCommerce. I was trying to import updated CSV file via import csv suite.

Explanation : I have four fields in my table. Say name, email, age, and mobile number.
Now I want to add two new fields to table like gender and income.
I have added all six field to csv file and also added column to db table.
but while importing it returns an error like `not parsed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image: This is my sample csv]

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of your imported data (or sample data, please don't post personal information) so we can check the formatting of your CSV?

Comment: Hi michael.. i have added an image of sample csv. Plz have a look.. Thanks M.

Comment: thanks. I'll take a look and see what I can do.

Comment: please see my revised answer, with additional information after testing.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, your issue is this:

> All values should be surrounded with double-quotes “” to ensure proper
>   parsing.

I took the file you provided, tested importing, and it initially failed. After surrounding it with double quotes, it parsed just fine, no error.

Read more about the [Customer/Order/Coupon CSV Import Suite](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/customer-order-csv-import-suite/) at the WooCommerce Documentation website. And read more about [Importing Products](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-importing-products/) at the WooCommerce Documentation website.